# Is it possible to find and style one character in a span with pure CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I think the answer here is "no", but some of the tricks css3 pseudo selectors can be harnassed to perform come close to magic at times.

I want to find and style the period character inside spans. Don't ask why, the context is ridiculous. Sadly the character can't be relied upon to exist in the same position on each occasion, so it has to be found. I *think* without JS this can't be done but wanted to confirm.

Comment: You are correct... **NO**. CSS selects **elements** and a character isn't one.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know it selects elements, but with `::before` and `::after`, for example, one can even place text  inside an element. There is a ::first-character selector. So executing some logic with CSS isn't impossible.

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

Comment: Techically no. `:first-letter` is styling a block level element's first letter not `nth-letter(x)` [so it wouldn't work for a span anyway]. Even if it were it **can't tell what that letter is.**

Comment: @Paulie_D The point about it working only on block-level elements I definitely overlooked, but I knew this otherwise wasn't a solution, was just hoping for some obscure pseudo-selection I could hijack, alas. Ty tho.

Answer (score 1):

Overall no... however you could wrap each character in an element, which you can then style.

A simple bit of JS can be used to do this.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#find-periods");
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\./g, '<span class="char-period">.</span>')
```

```css
.char-period{ color: red; font-size: 30px; }
```

```html
<p id="find-periods">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vitae tristique massa, ut convallis risus. Vestibulum maximus sed libero ut lacinia. Integer vel mollis ex. Nullam mattis ipsum in massa aliquet pharetra eget nec enim. In vitae sem at nibh mollis finibus. Quisque id pretium velit. Donec nec augue volutpat, sodales dui id, eleifend augue. Nulla lobortis congue est ut venenatis. Ut mollis nisi ac purus auctor, nec sollicitudin mi vestibulum. Integer tincidunt, metus sit amet euismod porta, nisl nisi accumsan lectus, id lacinia nunc arcu vitae massa. Nunc et tellus ante. In mattis ex sed sem hendrerit elementum. Ut leo libero, convallis sit amet massa et, tincidunt malesuada augue. Pellentesque consectetur maximus maximus. Duis suscipit dolor risus, sed egestas libero iaculis ac. Phasellus consectetur quam ipsum, in finibus leo fringilla a.
</p>
```

Comment: Yeah, appreciate the solution , alas it's not an option; I'm working with a standalone app that's based on Chromium and uses CSS to style it's contents; editing the stylesheets is one thing, injecting logic into the app itself is another.